Delete Row using C# DocumentFormat.OpenXml
I'm using C# DocumentFormat.OpenXml to edit excel file.but have some issues.
Hope everyone can help me to resolved this issues.
I want delete (real or empty) row， but it didn't work for me。
I'm using sheetData.Elements<Row>() it can't find empty row.
Have any function can do it Using C# DocumentFormat.OpenXml ?
before

after

I need to delete (Row > Row 93) all Row. Like Picture not only delete cell string. This is my code to delete excel row, but it didn't work.
static void DeleteRowsCompletely(string filePath, string sheetName, int startRow, int endRow)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);
            if (!sheets.Any())
            {
                throw new Exception("Sheet not found.");
            }

            var sheet = sheets.First();
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            for (uint i = (uint)startRow; i <= endRow; i++)
            {
                var row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowIndex == i);

                if (row != null)
                {
                    if (sheetData.Contains(row))
                    {
                        sheetData.RemoveChild(row);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value > endRow))
            {
                uint newRowIndex = row.RowIndex.Value - (uint)(endRow - startRow + 1);
                row.RowIndex.Value = newRowIndex;

                foreach (var cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    string oldCellReference = cell.CellReference.Value;
                    cell.CellReference = new StringValue(UpdateCellReference(oldCellReference, newRowIndex));
                }
            }

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }

    static string UpdateCellReference(string cellReference, uint newRowIndex)
    {
        string columnPart = new string(cellReference.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
        return $"{columnPart}{newRowIndex}";
    }


delete (real or empty) row and can't find empty row  -> but  according to your screenshoot, all the rows are empty, so that what kind of rows are required to be deleted?

Show us the code.

i need delete (Row > Row 93) all Row。Like Picture not only delete cell string

@PalleDue like below code

Here's my test in my side https://i.sstatic.net/zOlANLJ5.png  as you can see there's many empty rows in the execl file but the row counts is  5 so that I can't delete any row which index is more than 10. Could you please check in your side about the row counts?

I know it can't count empty row，but in my side i  don't want see empty row show up.

I tried to hide the extra empty rows. Just like what we discussed, the row count in my  file is 5 so that I can't remove rows which index is more than 10. Then I have a workaround to hide the rows and the test result is like below.
WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

var rowcounts = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Count();
var rowsToRemove = sheetData.Elements<Row>()
                    .Where(row => row.RowIndex > 10)
                    .ToList();
// Remove empty rows
foreach (var row in rowsToRemove)
{
    sheetData.RemoveChild(row);
}

for (uint rowIndex = 10; rowIndex <= 1048576; rowIndex++) // Excel has 1048576 rows in total
{
    Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex, Hidden = true };
    sheetData.Append(row); // Add hidden rows
}

worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();



Per my test, when we scroll down in Excel, it shows an infinite number of empty rows so that the scroll bar will never reach the end. I'm afraid this is the default behavior of the excel worksheet. So that maybe hide the rows shall be a workaround. And maybe limit the working area shall be another workaround.
